# Bibliographical note with text appearing before the reference

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I am trying to figure out how to have a bit of text in the bibliography before some entries.

If a normal bibliographical entry is something like

```
 [25] Ash, Culotta, Fahrenkamp-Uppenbrink, Malakoff, Smith, Sugden,
 Vignieri Science 2 August 2013: 341 (6145), 472-473.
```

What I am aiming to do is something like

```
[25] This is approached in the recent very interesting paper treating
 this topic. See, Ash, Culotta, Fahrenkamp-Uppenbrink, Malakoff, Smith,
 Sugden, Vignieri Science 2 August 2013: 341 (6145), 472-473.
```

With the format I am using, footnotes appear as bibliographic entries, so if there is a way to cite the full bibliographic entry and make sure it doesn't appear twice,

```
\footnote{This is approached in the recent very interesting paper treating this topic. See,\citeCommandIdontKnow{paperlabel}.}
```

That would work.

Comment: If you're using `biblatex`, try `\fullcite`

Comment: @karlkoeller Thanks for pointing it out. I am actually not using biblatex. I just realized I didn't know what it was and I assumed it was latex+bibtex in the usual way. I edited the tags. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I do not know which style you are using. Have you tried to use a `note` entry? It will be displayed at the end of the bib entry, but could be a workaround for this special case.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it [here](http://timmurphy.org/2011/02/15/using-an-organisation-name-as-an-author-in-bibtex/).

The way to do it is by turning the author entry into
a verbatim text.

This is done in bibtex by surrounding the field
with quotation marks "{...}

The only *problem* with this approach is that if natbib is reformatting the author names it won't do it as now it treats that field as a verbatim entry. The way I have solved it is quick and dirty but it only has to be done once. First I use the *bare* bibtex entry. For example,

```
@book{mattuck1976guide,
title={A Guide to Feynman Diagrams in the Many-body Problem},
author={Mattuck, R.D.},
isbn={9780486670478},
lccn={92004895},
series={Dover Books on Physics Series},
url={http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pe-v8zfxE68C},
year={1976},
publisher={Dover Publications, Incorporated}
}
```

Compile and the result is

> [61] R. Mattuck, *A Guide to Feynman Diagrams in the Many-
>   body Problem*, Dover Books on Physics Series (Dover
>   Publications, Incorporated, 1976).

Check how the author name is formatted and if I am happy with how 
it turns out I modify as described above

```
@book{mattuck1976guide,
title={A Guide to Feynman Diagrams in the Many-body Problem},
misc={Mattuck, R.D.},
author="{For a newcomers entry point I would recommend R. Mattuck}",
isbn={9780486670478},
lccn={92004895},
series={Dover Books on Physics Series},
url={http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pe-v8zfxE68C},
year={1976},
publisher={Dover Publications, Incorporated}
}
```

Which generates the following output

> [61] For a newcomers entry point I would recommend R. Mat-
>   tuck, A Guide to Feynman Diagrams in the Many-body
>   Problem, Dover Books on Physics Series (Dover Publica-
>   tions, Incorporated, 1976).

Which is what I needed.